# anything faster than .include?

Tags: ruby, arrays, include

I'm currently working with arrays and i decided to try and speed up one of my functions with replacing and iterative search of a sorted array with .include? much to my surprise the total run time of the program went from 2:12 to 9:53. confused by this i went to look at the source code for .include? and it turns out it's just an iterative check written in C

```
rb_ary_includes(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
        long i;

        for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
                if (rb_equal(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i), item)) {
                        return Qtrue;
                }
        }
        return Qfalse;
}
```

is there a faster way to determine whether a certain item is in a sorted array, maybe a gem? or do things need to be done the hard way with writing in your own binary search method?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of searching, it might make sense to convert your array to a hash (or set) and use the hash (or set) to do the lookups. Right tool for the job and all that...

Comment: You should consider keep an hash as an index, updating along with your list.

Comment: If the array is always sorted, It won't hurt to make your implementation of the basic binary search algorithm in ruby. It will be the fastest. Or, better, go the hash way as rightly pointed by mu is too short, if you can switch from array to hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @mu, however if you really want to use an array, and are using Ruby 2.0.0, you might want to check out the `bsearch` method.

```
arr = [1,2,3,5,6]
arr.bsearch { |x| 3 == x } # => 3
arr.bsearch { |x| 7 == x } # => nil

arr1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
arr1.bsearch { |x| '2' == x } # => "2"
arr1.bsearch { |x| '7' == x } # => nil
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch

Comment: `2.1.2 :030 > arr1
 => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
2.1.2 :031 > arr1.bsearch { |x| '2' == x }
 => nil`

Comment: Why am I getting nil for searching 2...

Comment: @TimothyLeung `bsearch` works with an expression that is false when the value is too low and true when it is matching or too high. So if you replace the `==` in your expression with `<=` it will function as expected.